# Bash command variable inside another command

Tags: linux, bash, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to execute a `ldapsearch` command inside a script.

Following does not work

```
ADMIN_USER="$(whoami)";

ldapmodify -h myldapserver  -p 23223 -D 'uid=$ADMIN_USER,ou=people,ou=company,dc=corpcom,dc=com' -w "$ADMIN_PWD" -f /tmp/reset_password.ldif.$PID;
```

The above code gets executed with following error `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)`

If hardcode the value like below, then it works.

```
ADMIN_USER="$(whoami)";

ldapmodify -h myldapserver -p 23223 -D 'uid=adminuser,ou=people,ou=company,dc=corpcom,dc=com' -w "$ADMIN_PWD" -f /tmp/reset_password.ldif.$PID;
```

Is there a sepcific reason for this? how will i be able to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash isn't expanding the variable because you enclosed it in single quotes. Change the string to use double quotes:

```
ADMIN_USER="$(whoami)";
ldapmodify -h myldapserver -p 23223 -D "uid=${ADMIN_USER},ou=people,ou=company,dc=corpcom,dc=com" -w "$ADMIN_PWD" -f /tmp/reset_password.ldif.$PID;
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781).

Comment: This skips having the single-quote around the arguments to `-D` just expands the variable alone

Comment: That's right, it's my assumption that is desired.

Comment: @Inian The single quotes in the original aren't passed to the command anyway; they are removed by the shell prior to calling the command. They are only used to escape each character contained in them.

Comment: @chepner : thought it is needed as part of the flag

Comment: @chepner : Also the syntax I used actually expanded the variable properly.

Comment: The expansion is not the problem; the *interpretation* of the expanded value by the shell is.